# Avoiding excessive sliderinput

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I am somewhat new to shiny but have experience in R.

In short, I have a shinyApp that currently implements 20 slider inputs, but that has left the UI looking nasty and cluttered. I've explored wrapping the input statement with div() to adjust the height but then I loose the slider's label. I've tried other inputs as well but I am looking for something more eloquent.

I recall someone who knows shiny well discussing small number inputs that overlay a map but I am having no luck online finding anything on it. Would someone be able to point me to a suitable resource?

Below is my code. I know there are instances where I can work in some reactive functions and do some general tidying but I will make those tweaks later on.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel(h2('Weather Application', align = 'center' )),

sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

  selectInput(inputId = 'fiscalmonth', 
              label = 'Select a month', 
              choices = c(1:12), 
              selected = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'ames', 
              label = 'AMES', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'atlanta', 
              label = 'ATLANTA', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'bangor', 
              label = 'BANGOR', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'bozeman', 
              label = 'BOZEMAN', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'columbus', 
              label = 'COLUMBUS', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'dallas', 
              label = 'DALLAS', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'denver', 
              label = 'DENVER', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'houston', 
              label = 'HOUSTON', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'lansing', 
              label = 'LANSING', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'losangeles', 
              label = 'LOS ANGELES', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'madison', 
              label = 'MADISON', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'memphis', 
              label = 'MEMPHIS', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'miami',
              label = 'MIAMI',
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100, 
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'minneapolis', 
              label = 'MINNEAPOLIS', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'peoria', 
              label = 'PEORIA', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'pittsburgh', 
              label = 'PITTSBURGH', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'richmond', 
              label = 'RICHMOND', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'sacramento', 
              label = 'SACRAMENTO', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'seattle', 
              label = 'SEATTLE', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1),

  #adding widgit for user to set individual city weight
  sliderInput(inputId = 'syracuse', 
              label = 'SYRACUSE', 
              min = 0, 
              max = 100, 
              value = 100,
              step = 1)
),

mainPanel(

  plotOutput('map', height = 800),

  plotOutput('scatter', height = 800)

)

)
)

server <- function(input, output){

output$map <- renderPlot({

country <- map_data('usa')

country %>% ggplot(aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat),
             size = input$ames/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15, 
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Ames')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Ames')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$atlanta/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Atlanta')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Atlanta')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$bangor/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Bangor')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Bangor')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$bozeman/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Bozeman')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Bozeman')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$columbus/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Columbus')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Columbus')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$dallas/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Dallas')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Dallas')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$denver/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Denver')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Denver')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$houston/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Houston')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Houston')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$lansing/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Lansing')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Lansing')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$losangeles/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Los Angeles')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Los Angeles')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$madison/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Madison')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Madison')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$memphis/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Memphis')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Memphis')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat),
             size = input$miami/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Miami')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Miami')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$minneapolis/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Minneapolis')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Minneapolis')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$peoria/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Peoria')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Peoria')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$pittsburgh/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Pittsburgh')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Pittsburgh')) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$richmond/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Richmond')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Richmond'), hjust = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$sacramento/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .15,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Sacramento')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Sacramento'), hjust = -0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat), 
             size = input$seattle/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .19,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Seattle')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Seattle'), hjust = -0.6) +
  geom_point(aes(Long, Lat),
             size = input$syracuse/7, colour = 'green', alpha = .19,
             data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Syracuse')) +
  geom_text(aes(Long, Lat, label = City), data = ctycord %>% filter(City == 'Syracuse'), hjust = -0.5) +
  theme_void()

})

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Maybe there is something here: http://gallery.htmlwidgets.org/

Comment: @HarlanNelson Thanks for your help! I will take a look.